# How can I run a graphic example from MS docs

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I found a code example in the MS docs regarding the `WriteableBitmap` class here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=netframework-4.8

There is a full example in the documentation and I'd like to copy it in a Visual Studio project and run it.

But if I create a WPF application, I don't get any file containing a Main() function.

And if I create a Console Application, I cannot add all references needed.

Which kind of projet should I create to copy/paste MS example code ?

Comment: WPF template project has MainWindow. add Image code in that window (and don't use `Window w` from example)

Answer (score 0):

Create a WPF application and just put the `Main` code in any method.

Then call the method from the constructor of `MainWindow`